# Can't set defaultValue using react.rb

Tags: react.rb

My code is
    `input(type: "text",  name: "name",  defalut_value: obj.name)`
and I try this too
    `input(type: "text",  name: "name",  defalutValue: obj.name)`

I always got 
    `<input type="text" name="name" data-reactid=".0.1.1.1.1">`
with no "defalutValue"

Comment: Is this just a typo? Should be default rather than defalut?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: try `defaultValue` (not `defalutValue`) (you had a typo in the string)

Long answer:

React only passes along standard attributes or data attributes (like "data-foo") to **built in tags** everything else is scrubbed off.   Standard attributes that have dashes, should be camel cased (i.e. defaultValue.)

The camel casing is a bit inconsistent and is planned to be fixed in 0.9 BTW

For now the rules are:

1) for built in tags, only standard attributes or attributes beginning with `"data-..."` are passed along.

2) if the html attribute has a dash (like `default-value`) the react attribute will be camel cased (like `defaultValue`) except for `data-` tags.

3) For application defined components you need to use a legal ruby variable name, and `class` and `style` attributes are handled specially.

Here is a working example http://goo.gl/abv28C

Comment: Thank you very much!It's very helpful!